# How to use querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get multiple elements with the same class name.
Basicially I like to duplicate a navigation menu, so I have two equal menus on one site. If I click on a link on MENU 1 the action should happen in MENU 1 and MENU 2.

**I have tried out to call them with a queryselectorAll but got no working results.**

Maybe a pro can help me out.

```
var menuEl = document.querySelectorAll('.menu');
document.mlmenu = new MLMenu(menuEl, {});
```

...

```
<!-- MENU 1 -->
<nav class="menu">
...
</nav>

<!-- MENU 2 -->
<nav class="menu">
...
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m816o1ne/

Comment: So, what exactly is the question? What problem are you having?

Answer (score 1):

> **document.querySelectorAll** Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's
>   nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object
>   returned is a NodeList.

So you can use it in following way:

```
var menuEl = document.querySelectorAll('.menu');
for(var i=0;i<menuEl.length;i++){
  console.log(menuEl[i]);
}
```

OR

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.menu'),function(elem){
  console.log(elem);
})
```